# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: students

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dob, :grade_status, :school_id

  belongs_to :school
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :location, :name

  has_many :students
end

class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @school = School.new
      @student = @school.students.build(params[:student])
      School.create(params[:school])
    end
end
```

Comment: You do nothing to make `students` accessible; no surprise here.

Comment: @DaveNewton, he shouldn't have to make `students` accessible when using `@school.students.build` - am I wrong? OP - is your params hash what you think it is? Make sure. If the students key is nested in the school key, then you aren't doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: @LoganSerman so what do you suggest that I should do? I am pretty new with association & helper form... your help will be very much appreciated been stuck in this problem for 2 whole hours now lol thanks

Comment: @LoganSerman Needs to accept nested attributes and be made accessible, which is confusing, because that's what you say in your answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton it isn't confusing. OP's original code is doing accepts_nested_attributes_for manually. In that case he does not need to make students accessible, he just needs to build his parameters correctly. My answer does use nested attributes. They are completely different solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :students` in the School model and add `:students_attributes` to the attr_accesible

Comment: you are welcome, for more info you can search about nested mass assignment , good luck

Answer (score 0):

Add `:students` to your list of `attr_accessible`. And buy on book about Rails.

Comment: now I got ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in HomeController#index

Comment: Gonna need more information than that. Add something to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `params` hash is including the 'students' key inside of the 'school' key. Is this accurate? It looks something like this:

```
{ school: { name: 'Foo', location: 'Bar', students: [...] } }
```

I will assume this is the case. You should use nested attributes, add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :students
```

to your School model. Also add `students_attributes` to your `attr_accessible` line in your School model.

In your view, you will need to use the `fields_for` helper so that Rails can build the `students_attributes` key in your params. It would look something like this:

```
form_for @school do |f|
   f.text_field :name
   f.text_field :location
   f.fields_for :students do |builder|
     builder.text_field :dob
     ...
```

(this should all be in ERB, Haml, or whatever you're using)

Here is the Railscast on nested forms: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 if you are still having trouble.

Comment: You should contribute to it, then. For a start, how about accepting this answer as correct?